# Using a CSS responsive grid generator how does the math work?

Tags: html, css, math, sass

I'm trying to understand how the math works out in css grid generators like this one: http://www.responsivegridsystem.com/calculator/

Using 12 columns and 1% margin it shows like:

```
.span_12_of_12 {
    width: 100%;
}

.span_11_of_12 {
    width: 91.58%;
}
.span_10_of_12 {
    width: 83.16%;
}

.span_9_of_12 {
    width: 74.75%;
}

.span_8_of_12 {
    width: 66.33%;
}

.span_7_of_12 {
    width: 57.91%;
}

.span_6_of_12 {
    width: 49.5%;
}

.span_5_of_12 {
    width: 41.08%;
}

.span_4_of_12 {
    width: 32.66%;
}

.span_3_of_12 {
    width: 24.25%;
}

.span_2_of_12 {
    width: 15.83%;
}

.span_1_of_12 {
    width: 7.416%;
}
```

I can calculate the rows without margin but am trying to understand how to add the margin into the equation.

The reasoning is I want to put this all in a mixin / for loop in my sass so that I can specify any amount of columns on a grid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here they are using approx calculation.

Calculating one of 12 grid = 7.416%

1. The total size of grid is 100%
2. If margin is 1% then the total margin of grid is 11%
3. Grid size (100%) - Margin (11%) = 89%
4. To find the size of 1 grid by dividing 89% / 12
5. Result is 7.416%

Now calculate 2 of 12 grid = 15.83%

1. Second grid = 7.416% + 7.416% = 14.832%
2. In second grid we have to add 1% margin because when we combine two grid the margin between them collapses so the total is 14.832% + 1% = 15.832%

SAME FOR THE NEXT GRIDS